# How to support Multi-Language apps for cocoa/objective c?

Tags: objective-c

guys, I am wondering how cocoa supports multilanguage (mac) apps?

I mean which is the more convenient way to design an interface/mvc to support multilanguage?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to start by reading this article:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html

and then go from there.

Cocoa and Cocoa Touch use nibs to define the interface and then you use a "strings" file to do your actual localization. In many cases, you'll wind up with one nib and many strings files (one for each localization in your application).

Comment: Usually your nib contains localisation as well, and you have multiple nibs. The placement/ordering of controls in one locale might not make sense in another locale, etc.

Comment: You're correct, it depends on your nib contents. If your object layout inside your nibs is locale-dependent, then you can take advantage of the additional automatic behavior that creating per-locale nibs can give you. In other cases, you can take advantage of the positioning format specifiers in the strings files.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would probably be [here](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/), or more specifically for Mac OS X development you could look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).